# Where does Photos store Live Photo videos?

Tags: photos, photos.app

The Photos app in OSX El Capitan can import Live Photos from my iPhone.  But when I look in the folder where photos are stored, `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters`, I don't see any videos there.  (Under iPhoto, Live Photos were imported as separate video and audio files.)  So where is the video piece stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  They are stored in `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/resources/modelresources`, though not in a folder structure that is easy to find your way around.

However, at least your video files will have the same name as photo files, for example `IMG_2727.jpg` and `IMG_2727.mov`.  Once Spotlight has indexed the folder, you should be able to search by filename from the Finder, if you restrict to looking inside the Photos library folder.  Or, you can use the Terminal, and `cd` to the Photos library folder, and then search with:

```
find . -name 'IMG_2727*'
```

Comment: In my case (OS X 10.12.1), my correlating Live Photos had a different name and were in `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/media/masters` with names like `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/media/masters/00/jpegvideocomplement_f.mov` (that went with an IMG_7216.JPG). it's disappointing these aren't stored alongside the originals in Masters.

Answer (score 4):

On OSX 10.12.4 with Photos version 2.0 (3150.4.120) they appear to be stored in `~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/resources/media/master/$NUM/00/jpegvideocomplement_$HEX.mov`.  These don't appear to be indexed by Spotlight.